# reactjs colour a table cell

Tags: html, reactjs, colors

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_bgcolor) tutorial to colour a cell of an html table in reactjs. Here is a minimal example:

```js
class Class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div><table><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#FF0000">test</td></tr></tbody></table></div>)
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Class/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

at the moment their is no added colour (It should be red). How can I fix this? Why does it not work? Thanks

I tried changing the version as was recommended however this break my code. Here is the modified code:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<body><div id="root"></div><script type="text/babel">

class Class extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div><table><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#FF0000">test</td></tr></tbody></table></div>)
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Class/>,document.getElementById('root'));</script></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using v0.14.6 of React.
The only thing I have changed is using v16.8.6 instead, and your code works:

```js
class Class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div><table><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#FF0000">test</td></tr></tbody></table></div>)
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Class/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Of course, it would be preferable to apply styles from CSS.

Comment: I believe styles need to be passed as objects in React? i.e.<td style={ background: "#FF0000 }></td>

Comment: thanks for getting a working example however I need a way to put this in a class and have it work so that I can use colour in a larger project, how can I do that?

Comment: @fred Updated my answer, the React version you used is too old and didn't support the `bgcolor` attribute